# Creating Pojo for Jackson JSON deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

Ok I have some JSON I get from a service that I am trying to create a POJO for. My JSON looks similar to:

```
[
{
    "id": "someid",
    "values": {
        "value1": {
            "id": "someid"
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": "391055",
    "values": {
        "value1": {
            "id": "someid"
        },
        "value2": {
            "id": "someid"
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": "someid",
    "values": {
        "value1": {
            "id": "someid"
        }
    }
}
]
```

and my POJO is like:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"values"})
public class ValueTranslation {

@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("values")
private Map<String, String> values;

public ValueTranslation(String id, Map<String, String> values) {
    this.id = id;
    this.values = values;
}
}
```

After I figure this out I will work on getting the inner string changed to some object, but I have no idea what is going wrong in the mapping. I have read several JACKSON tutorials and googled, but have found nothing to help me.

Comment: This `    "values": {
        "value1": {
            "id": "someid"
        },
        "value2": {
            "id": "someid"
        }
    }` doesn't fit to Map<String, String>

Comment: Ok Thanks I will create another object to use there.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It is a List of value translations. That is why it wasn't working.